# convert php array to array List

Tags: php, android, arrays, arraylist

My jsonobject returns the following string from a php data source:

```
String[] faili =  new String [] {object.getString("slikaordfail")};
-->
["San Diego_3.jpg","San Diego_2.jpg","San Diego_1.jpg"]
```

How can I get an array in java from this string?

Tried something like

```
 List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(faili));
```

but with the same result. It seems that the brackets from the php array are the problem. I don't like do delete them with string operations. There must be a more elegant way.

Debugger shows only one record:

```
0=  "["San Diego_3.jpg","San Diego_2.jpg","San Diego_1.jpg"]"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do not put your object.getstring inside the String Array initialization. the getstring call gives you a one long string, not multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gson library. 
Create custom class like this Details.

```
@SerializedName("slikaordfail")
private ArrayList<Details> eventDetailses;

public ArrayList<Details> getEventDetailses() {
    return eventDetailses;
}

public void setEventDetailses(ArrayList<Details> rentDetailses) {
    this.eventDetailses = rentDetailses;
}

 @SerializedName("event_pic")
private String eventPicture;

public String getEventPicture() {
    return eventPicture;
}

public void setEventPicture(String eventPicture) {
    this.eventPicture = eventPicture;
}
```

And in your Activity call.

```
Details details = gson.fromJson(result, Details.class);//result is your json data
ArrayList<Details> detailses = details.getEventDetailses();//getImages using detailses arrayList
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't have gson installed. Will try, when I have time.